# How to fix type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, components

I am working on an react app with redux but while rendering my dashboard component,I am facing this issue:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Layout`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:25058)
    at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:25086)
    at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:14052)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14112)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17632)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19080)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)

The above error occurred in the <div> component:

    at div
    at GridColumn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67497:25)
    at div
    at GridRow (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67602:25)
    at div
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67387:23)
    at div
    at Layout
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40833:6)
```

Here's my `app.js` and `index.js`:

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../src/clientDashboard/configureStore';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import clients from '../src/clientDashboard/actions/clientReducer';
import Layout from './clientDashboard/Layout';
export default combineReducers({
    clients: clients
});



const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
  
  <App />,
  
 </Provider></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root')

);
```

Here's my `app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Layout from './clientDashboard/Layout';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
        <Layout/>
        
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's my `Layout` Component:

`Layout.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Typography from './ui-components/Typography';
import Table from './Table/Layout';
import Input from './SearchInput';
import styled from './constants/style/styled';
import colorPalette from './constants/style/colorPalette';
import CreatePopup from './Form/Popup';


const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)`
  padding-right: 8px ;
`;


const StyledGridRow = styled(Grid.Row)`
  padding-top: ${props => props.paddingtop} !important;
  padding-bottom: ${props => props.paddingbottom} !important;
`;


const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <Grid columns='equal'>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column textAlign='left' width={13}>
          <Typography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='big' bold className='inline'>clients</Typography>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={3} textAlign='right'>
          <CreatePopup position='bottom right' triggertext='client' width='calc(100vw - 300px)' />
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <StyledGridRow paddingbottom='5px'>
        <Grid.Column width={6}>
          <Typography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='small' bold className='inline'>{'ui.label.client.list.allcaps'}</Typography>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column textAlign='right' width={10}>
          <Form>
            <StyledTypography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='small' className='inline'>{'ui.label.search.client'}</StyledTypography>
            <Input />
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </StyledGridRow>
      <StyledGridRow paddingtop='5px'>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Table />
        </Grid.Column>
      </StyledGridRow>
    </Grid>
  </div>
);


export default Layout;
```

When I run this app using `npm start` I get a blank white page with the above given error.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The errors says when inside `Grid.Column`, so looking at your render you have a `<Table/>`  `<Typography/>`  `<CreatePopup/>` & `<Form/>..   Maybe try console logging each to see which one is wrong.

Comment: How should I console them,can you elaborate? I am new to web d.